# regression model into table

Tags: r

I have a summary regression model I want to put into a table. However, it keeps coming up with an error. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have included a reproducible data and steps I have taken below.

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)
library(webshot)


x<-rnorm(1:20)

y<-(1:20)/10+x

m1<-lm(y~x) 

summary(m1)

test<-tab_model(m1, file="test.html")

webshot("test.html","test.png")


Could not load  file:///C:/Users/AB/Documents/test.html
Error in webshot("test.html", "test.png") : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 1
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. I have even changed my working directory - just to be sure. Is there any other better way than what I am currently doing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't assign the output of `tab_model()` to a variable - that prevents it from writing the HTML file. If you just run `tab_model()` without assigning it to `test` you'll be fine.

The following works for me:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)
library(webshot)

x<-rnorm(1:20)

y<-(1:20)/10+x

m1<-lm(y~x) 

summary(m1)

tab_model(m1, file="test.html")

webshot("test.html","test.png")
```

Comment: Alternatively, call test after assigning it. That is, after `test<-tab_model(m1, file="test.html")`
run `test`